# About Event_calendar.Showing only events for current user and not all events present

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

A couple of days ago I installed the event_calendar solution that is offered by https://github.com/elevation/event_calendar and everything is working fine.Now I've realized that I'm going to have several users and being things as they're right now any of my users is able to see **ALL** existing events in the db.

What I need is for each user is to only see the events he's being part of; so I thought to create one more migration called XXXXXXXXX_create_events_users_join.rb where I would only keep the users' and the events' ids.So how am I supposed to show on the actual calendar only the events that belong to the current user.Or is it creating that migration not the best approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution might work but it is much more complex than needed. Rails has a nice way of managing such thing internaly. Now what you need to do is:

1-> Create a migration: `add_user_id_to_events user_id:integer`

2-> Set the relationships:

in User model (user.rb):

> ```
> class User < ActiveRecord::Base
>     has_many :events
>     ....
> end
> ```

in Event model (event.rb):

> ```
> class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
>    has_event_calendar
>    belongs_to user
>    ....
> end
> ```

3-> Then in your events view you can use for example:

> ```
>  ...
>  <% @user.events.each do |event| %>
>     <tr>
>        <td><%= event.name %></td>
>        ....
>     </tr>
>  <% end %>
>  ...
> ```

and for the calendar you just need to change:

> ```
> @event_strips = Events.event_strips_for_month(@shown_month)
> ```

to something like

> ```
> @event_strips = current_user.events.event_strips_for_month(@shown_month)
> ```

Hope I helped!

Regards

Comment: @Xeroxoid.thx for the answer.I was away for a while so just saw your post.Meanwhile I was checking the calendar controller that comes with the gem and I guess I skipped the part where through the method  Event.event_strips_for_month(@shown_month) I can pass some conditions.So I'd call @event_strips = Event.event_strips_for_month(@shown_month,:conditions => ['user_id = ?', session[:user_id]]).And of course added an extra field on my events migration (t.references :user).So now I'm filtering all events by the user id. Regards.