# Rails belongs_to issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was trying to follow the answer provided by this post
[About Event_calendar.Showing only events for current user and not all events present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925627/about-event-calendar-showing-only-events-for-current-user-and-not-all-events-pre)

However when I tried to add the `belongs_to user` in the event model, it gives me the following error.

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method 'user' for #<Class:0x007fff15d1f6c0>):
  app/models/event.rb:3:in '<class:Event>'
  app/models/event.rb:1:in '<top (required)>'
  app/controllers/calendar_controller.rb:9:in 'index'


  Rendered .../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (2.8ms)
  Rendered .../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered .../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (23.6ms)
```

in my user.rb model I have included `has_many :events`

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: `belongs_to :user`  You have to prepend the `:` to make it a symbol, otherwise it's parsed as a method.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that. My bad! Thanks!

Comment: @numbers1311407 Make it an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`belongs_to :user`

You have to prepend the `:` to make it a symbol, otherwise it's parsed as a method.